# Integration between Couchdb and Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, couchdb

I am new to `Spring` and `Couchdb`. I have made a login interface in `Spring` that authenticates the user using `Spring-Security`.

Can anybody tell how to add user information at the time of log-in in a `Couchdb` Database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is no defintion of "spring-mvc annotation" based project. 
In this case, someone is trying to differentiate between the usage of annotations and xml-configuration based dependency injection and project configuration.

In case you are not familiar with the old way of using spring-mvc, you might take a look [on this example](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-multiactioncontroller-example/).

If you are planning to use spring-mvc in a new project, i would strongly recommend to use spring and spring-mvc with an annotation based style, as described in the [spring reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html).

Comment: One more query : I have made a login form for user login in `spring-mvc`. I want the user's entry to be created in a `couchdb` database at the time of login. Can you tell how to do this ?

Comment: I didnt use couchdb so far, but maybe https://github.com/rwitzel/CouchRepository is a good way to connect your spring application with couchdb.

Comment: I found this old topic but I want to point out a new project called couch-slacker. The project contains spring data implementation in standard spring data way. So if you want to use spring data and CouchDB with the possibility to change the database engine later couch-slacker you exactly for you. If some feature you use with Mongo DB is missing, let us know on Github.

Check it out [here](https://github.com/Majlanky/couch-slacker).
Releases of the project are in maven central so it is very easy to use it.

Disclaimer: I am the founder and tech lead of the project